# Как добавить несколько картинок к одному товару

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы:

1) Таблица `tovars` с полями

```
id - int (10) A_U
proizvoditel varchar(255)
```

2) Таблица `images` с полями

```
id - int(10) A_U
name varchar(255) --тут хранится путь картинки в таком в виде`/i/название_картинки.jpg   
tovar_id - int (10) - это поле служит для того чтобы понять какая картинка относится к какому товару.
```

Я не могу понять как мне сделать чтобы при добавлении данных картинки добавились к конкретному товару. **Меня интересует SQL запрос по сути только**
**код формы**

```
<form id="form2" name="upload" action="exit.php" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
Выберите файл для загрузки:
<input type="file" name="userfile[]"  multiple  accept="image/*" >
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

**php**

```
if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_FILES)){

$uploaddir = '/i/';
foreach ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $k=>$v){

if(($_FILES['userfile']['type'][$k] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$k] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$k] == 'image/png') && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$k] != 0 and $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$k]<=1024000))
{
    $ex = explode('.',$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$k]);
    $ex= end($ex);
    $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.'.$ex;
    $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";
    file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/_.txt","\n\r".__FILE__.":".__LINE__."\n\r".print_r($uploadfile,true));
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$k], $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].$uploadfile))
   {
        $c="INSERT INTO images (name) VALUES('$uploadfile') ";
        $q=$dbh->prepare($c);

        $q->execute();

    }       echo $uploadfile;
} 
}
}
```

Comment: добавляю через форму на странице, на языке php

Comment: @Batanichek, добавил код. По сути меня интересует только SQL запрос.

Comment: А как определяется к какому товару картинка ? может в форме должно быть поле связанное  c `id`товара ?

Comment: Вот в том и дело, я не знаю как привязать несколько картинок к одному товару, по сути может связи нужно между таблицами сделать.

Comment: Может использовать связующую `многие-ко-многим`?

Comment: можно, но как связь реализовать

Comment: у вас в таблице images , есть поле tovar_id. то есть если вы у всех картинок tovar_id=1 то они все будут связаны с товаром с id=1, вы хотите узнать как обновить tovar_id в таблице images?

Comment: Например можно при добавлении картинок `INSERT INTO images (name,tovar_id) VALUES('$uploadfile',$ID_TOVAR) `

Comment: да, верно я знаю если добавить в tovar_id = 1 - id товара то записи будут выводится) другое дело что я вручную могу так сделать и будет работать, но другое дело мне нужно сделать динамически этот момент. Пользователь вводит характеристики товара, загружает несколько картинок и вот на этом моменте хочется определиться что картинки будут иметь id конкретного товара. И так со следующими товарами.

Comment: Ну значит вам нужно получить сначала id товара подходящего под характеристики. + если их много то я бы сделать еще одну таблицу просто со связями товар картинка

Comment: А если мне нужно будет изменить картинки для конкретного товара то как будет выглядеть UPDATE запрос, подскажите пожалуйста  ?

Comment: думаю как то так `UPDATE images
SET tovar_id=$ID_TOVAR
WHERE id in ($ID_IMG)`  в случае если вы знаете какие картинки к какому товару хотите прикрепить

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в форму вам нужно вставить скрытым полем идентификатор товара:

```
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="tovar_id" VALUE="здесь идентификатор товара">
```

Во-вторых, в запросе вставки записи в таблицу изображений нужно указывать не только картинку, но и `ID` товара:

```
INSERT INTO images(name, tovar_id) VALUE (uploadfile, tovar_id)
```

Comment: про скрытое поле не очень понял, если я буду новый товар добавлять  то идентификатор сам создаться новый т.к. в бд на поле id стоит автоинкримент. Вы привели пример на основе моего кода но добавление будет идти сразу в две таблицы в одном запросе.

Comment: После добавления новой записи в таблицу товаров нужно получить идентификатор новой записи и использовать его при вставке записей в таблицу изображений.
При редактировании товара также надо понимать, к какому товару будет добавляться изображение.

Answer (score -2):

```
ALTER TABLE "tvoya_baza" CHANGE "tovars" "products" DATATYPE;
```

Comment: напишите пояснение что даст мне этот запрос даст ?